# go micro application always getting "/greeter-srv" no such file or directory kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have trying to install go micro application, but its always getting below error,

```
`   Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>           default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/greeter-7d7c644bdc-dk5q2 to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    9s (x4 over 3m10s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "12345.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest"
  Normal   Pulled     9s (x4 over 61s)    kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "460378929709.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest"
  Normal   Created    8s (x4 over 59s)    kubelet, minikube  Created container greeter
  Warning  Failed     8s (x4 over 56s)    kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "greeter": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/greeter-srv\": stat /greeter-srv: no such file or directory": unknown
`
```

i have used this [doc](https://github.com/micro/examples/tree/master/kubernetes) for installation, as per this doc installed deppentency etcd and NAT , and its running fine.
Any one is created this micro application in kubernetes, i have doubt my Dockerfile it self have any issue or yaml,
can u clear me if i run any wrong , i did not get any correct doc for kubernetes installation from site.

I used below yaml file for kubernetes deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: greeter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: greeter-srv
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: greeter-srv
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: greeter
          command: [
        "/greeter-srv",
      ]
          image: 12345.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: greeter-port
          env:
          - name: MICRO_SERVER_ADDRESS
            value: "0.0.0.0:8080"
          - name: MICRO_BROKER
            value: "nats"
          - name: MICRO_BROKER_ADDRESS
            value: "nats-cluster"
          - name: MICRO_REGISTRY
            value: "etcd"
          - name: MICRO_REGISTRY_ADDRESS
            value: "etcd-cluster-client"
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ap-south-1-ecr-registry
```

Dockerfile

```
  FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add make git go gcc libtool musl-dev
WORKDIR /go/src/
# Configure Go
ENV GOROOT /usr/lib/go
ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH /go/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src ${GOPATH}/bin

COPY . .
COPY greeter-srv /go/src/
RUN make

RUN apk add ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/* && \
    [ ! -e /etc/nsswitch.conf ] && echo 'hosts: files dns' > /etc/nsswitch.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/greeter-srv"]
```

service file name greeter-srv

```
import (
    "github.com/micro/go-micro/v2"
)
func main() {
    service := micro.NewService(
        micro.Name("greeter")
    )
    service.Init()
    service.Run()
}
```

I have build with above docker file then tag and push to aws ecr , then i used that registory in kubernetes yaml file.

Comment: Sorry not following - have you successfully done `docker build...` and `docker run...` from your workstation using that Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, i can start using docker local build with below docker-compose file

`server:
  command: server
  build: .
  ports:
  - "8080:8080"
  - "8081:8081"
  - "8082:8082"`

Comment: In the Dockerfile, how does the application get into the container `/` directory?  Can you run this without the `command:` override in either your Compose or Kubernetes setup (so, fix the image's `ENTRYPOINT` to be the correct default value)?

Comment: @DavidMaze Exactly , its my mistake , `ENTRYPOINT` should be correct path, i have corrected that , then i build and pushed cer, now i getting different error `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"` ,why ?

Comment: Are you accidentally copying in a prebuilt binary from the host?  (And then `make` decides the binary is up to date and doesn't need to be rebuilt, but it has incorrect shared-library dependencies?)

Comment: used pre-build files seems fine thanks @DavidMaze

Comment: Hi @shufilkhan, did you manage to solve the problem? If yes, could you please add an answer and accept it so if someone from community have same problem would find the answer here?

Comment: @jt97, that error resolved, its not up and getting  different error
`file=auth/auth.go:31 level=info Auth [noop] Authenticated as com.foo.service.hello-c7777f99-72ca-46c8-9df1-0fac44f977d4 issued by go.micro`

`file=v2@v2.8.0/service.go:206 level=info Starting [service] com.foo.service.hello`

`file=hello/main.go:30 level=fatal listen tcp 10.108.17.120:30590: bind: cannot assign requested address`

Comment: @shufilkhan paste your service.yaml file

Comment: @DashrathMundkar, i got the issue , I have mension `ENV`  as  `MICRO_BROKER_ADDRESS`  in deployment file , but that is not at all connecting with host , .[deployment-file (https://github.com/SHUFIL/test-kube-micro/blob/master/hello)] , [service-list] (https://github.com/SHUFIL/test-kube-micro/blob/master/service)

 log     `error Broker [nats] connect error: nats: Authorization Violation`

Answer (score 1):

`stat /greeter-srv: no such file or directory"`  this is due to Dockerfile mensioned `WORKDIR /go/src/` and `ENTRYPOINT ["/greeter-srv"]`  this is wrong , should be used `ENTRYPOINT ["/go/src/greeter-srv"]`

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile caused the issue change the ENTRYPOINT to `/go/src/greeter-srv`